# How to reverse data of a column into another column in MySql?

Tags: sql, mysql

I need to run a script to update a field of a table in mysql by reversing the string stored in another field of the same table. Original column is term and the one to be filled with the reversed is revTerm. I use this, but it produce an error. Any suggestions?

```
UPDATE `tu_cla_terms` WHERE tId = '11583' SET revTerm = REVERSE(term)
```

Comment: `UPDATE tu_cla_terms SET revTerm = REVERSE(term)  WHERE tId = '11583'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the syntax of an `UPDATE` query wrong. `SET` comes before `WHERE`:

```
UPDATE `tu_cla_terms` SET revTerm = REVERSE(term) WHERE tId = '11583'
```

If `tId` is a numeric column you don't want quotes around its value either.